# Check If A 2-Dimensional ArrayList Contains A Particular ArrayList - Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a 2-dimensional ArrayList that Contains ArrayLists of Integers.

2D ArrayList is defined like this:

```
List<List<Integer>> puzzleArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

The puzzleArray ArrayList contains ArrayLists of Integers and I want to be able to check if puzzleArray contains a certain ArrayList inside it.

For example:
I want to check if puzzleArray contains the exact ArrayList <1,2,3,4,0,6,7,8,9> called puzzle

I tried:

```
puzzleArray.contains(puzzle)
```

But it doesn't seem to work

How do I do this in Java please?

Comment: what doesn't seem to work exactly? what is the result of your trial?

Comment: I had that statement as the condition of an if statement and it isn't satisfying the condition even when puzzleArray does not contain puzzle ```(puzzleArray.contains(puzzle) == false)```

Comment: well, it isn't working for another reason, because if `puzzleArray` contains `puzzle`, it would evaluate to `true`